# Remove a line config block from a device config using regex in perl

Tags: regex, perl, replace, line, config

I am working on a perl based project. I have a device config in the form of a string. I want to replace all the line configuration blocks with some other template using regex.

I have 4 types of line configurations in my device config :-

1. line vty
2. line console or line con
3. line template
4. line default

So I want to replace the complete block of line configuration with my own set of lines.

Example :-

```
$config = "enable password xyz
enable secret 4 tnhtc92DXBhelxjYk8LWJrPV36S2i4ntXrpb4RFmfqY
ip classless
ip subnet-zero
no ip domain lookup
line vty 0 7
 transport input ssh telnet
 exec-timeout 720 0
 password xyz
 login
line vty 0 8
 exec-timeout 720 0
line con 0
 password xyz
!
line template vty
timestamp
exec-timeout 720 0
!
line template vty
timestramp
line console
exec-timeout 0 0
!";
```

Usually after each line config block there is a exclamation mark as a delimiter, but there can be a case when it is just a new line so i need to handle that also.

The approach that I am thinking is check for the word line in the config and check till the ! (exclamation mark as delimiter).

I tried the following code :-

```
my $ios_line_vty_config = "line vty 0 4\ntransport input ssh telnet\nexec-timeout 720 0\npassword abc\nlogin local\n!\n";

my $sub_os_type = "IOSv";

my $vty_flag = 0;

my @config_lines = split /\n/, $node_config;

for my $line(@config_lines){

    if (!$vty_flag && $line =~ /^line\s+vty.*/){
          $vty_flag = 1;
          print "\nline vty Matched:: Remove line---> $line \n";
          $line = '';
          next;
       }
       print "flag = $vty_flag\n";
       if ($vty_flag){

          if($line =~ /!|line/){
            print "line = $line\n";

            if ($sub_os_type eq "IOSv"){
              $line = $ios_line_vty_config.$line;
            }
            print "\nReplaced Line ---------> $line \n";
            $vty_flag = 0;
          }
          else {
          print "\nRemoved Line ---------> \n\n$line \n";
          print "\nsub_os_type :: $sub_os_type\n";
          $line = '';
        }
       }

}
```

How can I do this ? Please help me out..!!!

Comment: I am trying to just mach the blocks first using this $config =~ /(line\s*template.*!)$/ms;

This is just for line template

Comment: Please add your code into question and expected output.

Comment: serenesat I have pasted the tried code its just replacing the first line vty block but stops at the second consecutive block. Hope you will get what i am trying here..

Answer (score 1):

I find it helpful to sometimes write the code exactly how you would describe the problem. If I understand you correctly you want to rewrite some lines that contain "line" blocks. Some line blocks are "line vty" blocks and you want to replace their contents with something else. You get to the end of a block either when you read a ! or the start of a new line block. Here is your code rewritten a bit to match my understanding of the problem and using your $config scalar holding the lines:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
sub printBlock($$); #declare sub taking 2 parameters
my $config = "enable password xyz
enable secret 4 tnhtc92DXBhelxjYk8LWJrPV36S2i4ntXrpb4RFmfqY
ip classless
ip subnet-zero
no ip domain lookup
line vty 0 7
 transport input ssh telnet
 exec-timeout 720 0
 password xyz
 login
line vty 0 8
 exec-timeout 720 0
line con 0
 password xyz
!
line template vty
timestamp
exec-timeout 720 0
!
line template vty
timestramp
line console
exec-timeout 0 0
!";

print "$config\n========== old above ============= new below =================\n";
# DEBUG adding * to the start of lines so replacements are easy to see....
my $ios_line_vty_config = "*line vty 0 4\n*transport input ssh telnet\n*exec-timeout 720 0\n*password abc\n*login local\n*!\n";
my @config_lines = split(/\n/, $config);
my $block = "";
for my $line (@config_lines)
{
    $line =~ s/\s+$//; # remove trailing white space - make consistent
    if ($line =~ m/^line/) #start of block
    {
        printBlock($block, $ios_line_vty_config);
        $block = "$line\n";
    }
    elsif ($line =~ m/^!?$/) # ! or empty line signals end of block
    {
        $block .= "$line\n";
        printBlock($block, $ios_line_vty_config);
        $block = ""; #reset
    }
    elsif ($block) # in block
    {
        $block .= "$line\n";
    }
    else # outside of a block
    {
        print "$line\n";
    }
}
printBlock($block, $ios_line_vty_config);

sub printBlock($$)
{
    my $block = shift;
    my $replacement = shift;
    #decide here if replacing block ...
    $block = $replacement if ($block =~ m/line\s+vty/s); # replace block if it is a "line vty" block...
    print $block if ($block);
}
```

And here is what I see as output: Note I put *'s in front of the replacement lines so it was easier to debug.

```
schumack@daddyo2 12-18T0:45:59 312> ./test.pl
enable password xyz
enable secret 4 tnhtc92DXBhelxjYk8LWJrPV36S2i4ntXrpb4RFmfqY
ip classless
ip subnet-zero
no ip domain lookup
line vty 0 7
 transport input ssh telnet
 exec-timeout 720 0
 password xyz
 login
line vty 0 8
 exec-timeout 720 0
line con 0
 password xyz
!
line template vty
timestamp
exec-timeout 720 0
!
line template vty
timestramp
line console
exec-timeout 0 0
!
========== old above ============= new below =================
enable password xyz
enable secret 4 tnhtc92DXBhelxjYk8LWJrPV36S2i4ntXrpb4RFmfqY
ip classless
ip subnet-zero
no ip domain lookup
*line vty 0 4
*transport input ssh telnet
*exec-timeout 720 0
*password abc
*login local
*!
*line vty 0 4
*transport input ssh telnet
*exec-timeout 720 0
*password abc
*login local
*!
line con 0
 password xyz
!
line template vty
timestamp
exec-timeout 720 0
!
line template vty
timestramp
line console
exec-timeout 0 0
!
```

There are two line block replacements which I think is what you were looking for.